# FreeCAD: FemAnalysis Python module missing

Tags: finite-element-method, cad

After trying to execute the [GMSH macro by `psicofil`](https://github.com/psicofil/Macros_FreeCAD) I got an error:

```
import FemAnalysis
<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>: No module named 'FemAnalysis'
```

I have installed GMSH. The problem is I can't find that module on the internet.

Comment: you are trying to execute really old code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is an ancient macro - V 0.16 - which stopped working in V 0.17. That's according to someone on the FreeCAD Forum.
Apparently the Gmsh panel does everything the macro did.
Looking at the FreeCAD GitHub, my guess is that FemAnalysis was rewritten in C++ & so is not an importable module. But I'm no hacker.